# Locking and ref values from external function

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to track down a bug that I think might be related to the applications multithreading. I've simplified the code below:

```
class Outer {
  private static int count;

  //this function is called from multiple threads in quick succession
  public void DoFoo() {
    Inner.Increment(ref count);
  }
}

class Inner {
  private readonly static object mLock = new object();
  public static string Increment(ref count) {
    lock (mLock) (
      if (count > 1000)
        count = 0;
      count++;
    }
    return count.ToString();
  }
}
```

Can the locking guarantee the safety of a variable passed in that way? Is there any copying of count going on that seems non-obvious and may break the memory safety? I was thinking it might return a new int and do the assignment at the end of the method or something. Apart from that it's my understanding that the lock section would handle any caching issues.

The error which bought the issue to our attention was seemingly one of the threads having a stale version of count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that some other thread could read directly `Outer.count` when it is == 0, because you can access `Outer.count` without first having obtained a lock (normally as written in your code, `count` can be 0 only before the first call to `Inner.Increment`, from then on it can only have a value between 1 and 1001)

Lockless can be done in this way:

```
class Inner
{
    public static string Increment(ref int count)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int original = count;
            int next = original;

            if (next > 1000)
            {
                next = 0;
            }

            next++;

            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, next, original) == original)
            {
                return next.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calculating a `next` value and using it (through `Interlocked.CompareExchange`) only if `count` hasn't changed in the meantime.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but would it get the latest value when the lock statement is entered (because it's a reference) or will it stick with the stale value?

Comment: Will that solve the problem of the stale value being passed in from outer?

Comment: Yes, because the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` will "fail" (and force another cycle of the `while`) if the `original` isn't "correct" (for example because it contains a stale value, or because another thread updated `count`)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. This will potentially skip numbers though won't it?

Comment: @flukus It won't "skip" numbers... Someone (some other thread) will have "taken" them. So every number will be taken from someone, and everyone will get different numbers (up to 1001, then the numbers repeat). `Interlocked.CompareExchange` does nothing if the "real current" value is different than the third parameter.